# Ember component block scope within a view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an `Ember.View` with a template which accesses the view's properties, something like this:

```
{{view.someProperty}}
```

I want to wrap it in a component like this:

```
{{#my-component}}
  {{view.someProperty}}
{{/my-component}}
```

The [Ember component docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) tell me that the block is rendered with the parent context, but suddenly I'm not able to access properties using `view.someProperty`.

Is this a known issue? Can anyone help me find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It turns out that the view property (helper?) inside the block is a reference to the *component's* view. This means that I need to pass properties in and then reference them with `view.property` like this:

```
{{#my-component someProperty=view.someProperty}}
  {{view.someProperty}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Comment: I think all you'll need is {{someProperty}} inside your component template.

Comment: That won't work with the block content as it's rendered in the context of the parent view, not the component.